# How to get statistics to work with snippet for YouTube API

Tags: javascript, react-native, youtube, youtube-api

After gone thru the documentation and other solutions proposed on SO, it seems like `statistics` can only works with `id` but not `snippet`?

My app is letting user to search keyword and return a list, and for each and every videos, showing number of likes, something like below

[image]

My sample request is as below:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&type=video&q=rihanna&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Is it really how it should be? By querying a list of 50 or more videos at once, then firing 50 individual call just to get likes? It seems very bad and is there any chance I can return `statistics` along with videos?

**P/S: Now I truly see the value of Graphql**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official Youtube API for [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#usage) states that you can only pass the "snippet" parameter.

> **part**  *string* The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of
>   one or more search resource properties that the API response will
>   include. Set the parameter value to **snippet**.

The next thing to do after retrieving the videos with their corresponding IDs is to use that in [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) which can accept "statistics" parameter.

Usage
The id parameter value is a comma-separated list of YouTube video IDs. You might issue a request like this to retrieve additional information about the items in a playlist or the results of a search query.

Comment: In order words, while trying to load this page, i need to first fire first call to get a list of 50 videos, and firing another 50 API calls so that i can have the view as above right? That would be 51 calls in total..So there is no alternatives to avoid this amount of calls?